# How to call a target from a different makefile?

Tags: makefile

I am having trouble executing a target from a different makefile. Here is what I am doing

```
${MAKE} target -f makefile-location
```

What ends up happening is it is trying to execute the whole makefile instead of that specific target which is causing it to fail. I only need it to run that specific target.

UPDATE:

Now I am thinking that it is executing the macros only before the targets. It fails at the include line but I am not sure if it is supposed to execute that when I am calling a specific target.

```
### MAKEFILE BEGINS###

.SILENT 

PROJCONFIG := ${PROJ_CFG}

PATH := directory 

include ${PATH}/config.cfg
```

Comment: Try specifying the options *before* the target: `${MAKE} -f makefile-location target` .

Comment: Usually, I put targets at the command line end : `${MAKE} -f makefile-location target`

Comment: Didn't work. Although I am wondering now if it executing the lines before the target first. I will update the post with what I am talking about

Comment: The order of options and target doesn't matter.  But this question doesn't have enough information for us to answer it.  What exactly is the complete rule you're trying to run?  What output do you see?  Why do you think it's trying to "execute the whole makefile"?  What does that mean to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you perhaps thinking that Make works its way through the Makefile starting from the given target?  If so, you would have a wrong model of what's happening.

The way Make works is that (1) it parses the *entire* Makefile, including anything indicated by an `include`, before (2) establishing which target it is to satisfy (either given on the command line, or taking the first target encountered as the default), and then (3) establishes what actions it has to execute to satisfy that target.

The order of the targets inside the Makefile is arbitrary, with the single exception of the first target encountered, which is used as the default if no target is given on the command line.

That is, there's no top-to-bottom logic in a Makefile, that you might expect if you're thinking of it as a ‘normal’ programming language.

Thus, in answer to your (implicit) question, if it is failing on the `include`, then it will do so irrespective of what targets it it is trying to satisfy.  If it is failing there, then there is something wrong with the (Makefile) syntax inside the `.cfg` file.